Does Azure OpenAi Batch processing supports Structured output?
Does Azure OpenAI GlobalBatch GPT-4o deployment support "Structured output"? With response_format="json_schema" (and valid schema) it returns an empty output (Sweden Central Azure region). Without structured output it works fine, and GlobalStandard 4o model (same version) produces the structured output as expected.
I tried it with a request that worked fine with OpenAI Batch Structured output near the end of this conversation, and on Azure it returns an empty file.
So, does it mean that it is not supported on Azure, yet? Or is it some bug of me/Azure?
Request that worked with OpenAI and returns an empty file on Azure:
{"custom_id": "request-1", "method": "POST", "url": "/chat/completions", "body": {"model": "gpt-4o-batch", "messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful math tutor. Guide the user through the solution step by step."}, {"role": "user", "content": "how can I solve 8x + 7 = -23"}], "max_tokens": 4096, "response_format": {"type": "json_schema", "json_schema": {"name": "math_response", "schema": {"type": "object", "properties": {"steps": {"type": "array", "items": {"type": "object", "properties": {"explanation": {"type": "string"}, "output": {"type": "string"}}, "required": ["explanation", "output"], "additionalProperties": false}}, "final_answer": {"type": "string"}}, "required": ["steps", "final_answer"], "additionalProperties": false}, "strict": true}}}}

Same request without the response_format or with 'json_object' format works fine.
I am using a deployment in the Sweden Central region, if it matters.


Based on documentation for structured output, you should deploy a GPT-4o model with version 2024-08-06.

And, based on documentation for batch processing, the deployment type should be Global batch.


So, have you tried your Rest API with a deployment of type Global batch?
because you mentioned that when you try it with a GlobalStandard deployment, it returns an empty output.

Hi. yes, the answer is in my very first sentence: "Does Azure OpenAI GlobalBatch GPT-4o deployment support "Structured output"?"

Based on documentation, structured outputs are not yet supported for Batch Processing.
